Contour line colour in R rasterVis contourplot
In R, I am using rasterVis::contourplot to draw contour lines of a 2-D array of values on a regular grid of points.
I know that contour lines can have different colours depending on the field values, but I want to have the same colour for all contour lines. I can do this, it is rather straightforward, but all contour lines are black.
I would like, and I think this should be possible, to use a different colour: all contour lines red, for example.
I thought that this was easy, but I could not find how to do it.
How to do it?

Your question lacks programming code... that being said, if you use rasterVis::levelplot(contour = T... you can use par.settings = list(add.line = list(col = "red")) If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex() and any libraries you are using. Check it out: making R reproducible questions.

Thanks @Kat !
I did not add code because my question is quite general. And your answer is what I was looking for. By the way I did indicate that I am using library rasterVis.
Thank you again!
